# In php, why array_unshift() is named unshift?

Tags: php

As we know, there are four functions that can be used to insert into and delete from an array:

1. array_push()
2. array_pop()
3. array_unshift()
4. array_shift()

What's the meaning of `array_unshift()` and `array_shift()`, I mean why they are named like this?

Comment: If you want to know what those functions do, look at the manual?

Comment: PHP's naming conversion is already messy a lot.

Comment: What would you like them to be named instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's historical. Whereas in newer languages we probably wouldn't call it "shift" any more, older terminology from Perl includes the [**shift**](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) keyword, whose job is to:

> [Shift] the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by 1 and moving everything down.

This is often used with the `@_` array, which contains function arguments, and `shift` would provide access to them one at a time.

PHP, in its early days when Perl was still widely used for web programming, has simply taken this terminology, added the "inverse" `unshift` and left it.

Another example is [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), which is named after the *libc* `glob()` function. I imagine the intent was to make these functions familiar to those coming to PHP from existing languages, but in retrospect a decade or so later, perhaps the terms have aged poorly.

Comment: I have always hated these antiquated and confusing terms as well.

These days, I would hope they would be more logical:
1. array_push()  ->  array_append()
2. array_unshift()  ->  array_prepend()
3. array_shift()  ->  array_ltrim()
4. array_pop()  ->  array_rtrim()

Comment: I have also always wished for basic array_insertat() and array_deleteat() functions to simply insert/delete elements at any position without having to hack it apart with array_splice() first:

1. array_insertat(array, position, value) → returns boolean (or numeric)
2. array_deleteat(array, index) → returns boolean (or numeric)

In most cases, these could also be used in place of array_append/array_ltrim by using position 0, and in place of array_ltrim/array_rtrim when used with array_key_last().

Just my 2¢

Answer (score 2):

I can't find a definitive source for this, but my guess is that it stemmed from a familiarity with [shift registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_register), which behave in a similar manner.

You'll find [similar functions in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html), which PHP borrows a lot from. I would guess Perl also borrowed from other sources too, but ultimately, you'll get to a language designer who felt it was logical to call the operation 'shift' as it was similar to a shift register.

Other languages use the same naming idiom, for example [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [ActionScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000748.html), but other languages might use other terms, like queue/dequeue - see [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.dequeue.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`array_shift()` shifts the first value of the array off and returns it, shortening the array by one element and moving (**shifting**) all the other values down.

Comment: I think he's more asking about origins of the way these have been named

Comment: I read the question as "what does 'shift' mean in the content of these function names", but perhaps you're correct.